# Using SHA-256 in policy INF file

Tags: ssl, windows, certificate-authority

I have a CA policy inf file for an offline certificate request:

```
[Version]  
Signature="$Windows NT$"  
[PolicyStatementExtension]  
Policies=InternalPolicy  
[InternalPolicy]  
OID=1.2.3.4.1455.67.89.5  
Notice="Legal Policy Statement"  
URL=https://pki.corp.contoso.com/pki/cps.txt  
[Certsrv_Server]  
RenewalKeyLength=2048  
RenewalValidityPeriod=Years  
RenewalValidityPeriodUnits=5  
CRLPeriod=weeks  
CRLPeriodUnits=1  
LoadDefaultTemplates=0  
AlternateSignatureAlgorithm=1  
[CRLDistributionPoint]  
[AuthorityInformationAccess]
```

The certificate request is successful. But the certificates are using an old algorithm:

```
Signature algorithm: sha1RSA
Signature hash algorithm: sha1
```

How can I update the policy file to SHA-256?

Answer (score 1):

This is configured in the superior CA which signs your request - not in the request itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to communicate the desire *"I want this hashed with SHA256 instead of with SHA1, please!"* in the request itself. (And I've got no idea about this INF file method there.)

Instead you just configure the whole Microsoft CA (ADCS) to use SHA256.

Details here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pki/2013/09/19/upgrade-certification-authority-to-sha256/

The gist is to run this on the ADCS server:

```
certutil -setreg ca\csp\CNGHashAlgorithm SHA256
net stop certsvc
net start certsvc
```